# Azure Data Factory copy data is slow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Source database: PostgreSQL hosted on Azure VM D16s_v3
Destination database: SQL Server developer edition hosted on Azure VM D4s_v3
Source database is around 1TB in size
Destination database is empty with existing schema identical to source database

Throughput is only 1mb/s. Nothing helps. (I've selected max DIU) SQL Server doesn't have any keys or indexes at this point.

Batch size is 10000

See screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This may give some insight into where you might want to tune your data copy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got nailed by something similar when using ADF to copy data from an on-premises Oracle source to an Azure SQL Database sink. The same exact job performed via SSIS was something like 5 times faster. We began to suspect that something was amiss with data types, because the problem disappeared if we cast all of our high-precision Oracle NUMBER columns to less precision, or to something like integer.

It got so bad that we opened a case with Microsoft about it, and our worst fears were confirmed.

The Azure Data Factory runtime decimal type has a maximum precision of 28. If a decimal/numeric value from the source has a higher precision, ADF will first cast it to a string. The performance of the string casting code is abysmal.

Check to see if your source has any high-precision numeric data, or if you have not explicitly defined schema, see if you're perhaps accidentally using string.

Comment: That's a great comment. Thank you. We do have a bunch of columns with this exact problem. we ended up just using the slow version since we only do it once a month, but this is good to know.

Comment: I am glad this helped. I was told that the ADF team is working on supporting higher precision. This is unfortunate, because SSIS already has DT_NUMERIC with a maximum precision of 38, which is much better. This feels like a glaring omission on an "enterprise" product. So, there is some hope for the future on this.

Comment: I am having same issue. But I have 61 columns and most of having long text. In SQL we have varchar(max). How to deal with it?

Comment: @Rohi_Dev_1.0 Hi! What is the challenge you are experiencing? Perhaps it can be a new question on its own.

Answer (score -2):

Increase the batch size to 1000000.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using TableName option then you should have that Table inside Dataset dropdown box. If you are extracting using SQL query then please check inside Dataset connection, click on edit and remove table name.

I had hit the same issue. If you select the query option and provide tablename in dataset, then you are confusing Azure Datafactory and making it ambiguous to decide on which option.